# imageView and VideoView not matching even in FrameLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout and I want to cover the videoView by imageView. How can I make the image to exactly cover the video.
here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#576c93"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/red"

          />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla "
        android:textColor="#f5f5dc"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I am using the Framelayout but the result is the imageview and videoview dont overlap completely... how can i fix this?

the screen in my .xml graphical view looks like this:
[image]

Comment: How does the resulting screen look like? Can you share it also?

Comment: I added the Picture above. the grey part is the part doesnt match. so still part of the video at top is showing..

Comment: What is @drawable/red?

Comment: it is the red image which is over the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your `ImageView`   `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` .

If you set background to your image (by attribute `android:background`) you will see that your VideoView is covered by ImageView fully. So scaleType can help you solve the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Let ask autor, did it help to him? Luigi Saggese, if you can't understand what I wrote I think it is your problem, not my or author's. Agree?

Comment: in one device it solved it. but for bigger devices (nexus 7) it is not overlapping again..

Comment: try to play with other scaleTypes

Comment: and if it not help you just try set you image as background(instead src)